# How to implement GeckoView?

Tags: android, gecko, geckoview

I want to implement GeckoView into my app but I always get the following errors:

1. When I just implement it as described in this Link: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView

The following error occurs when installing the app:

> Installation failed with message Failed to commit install session 
>   2023122124 with command cmd package install-commit 2023122124. Error:
>   INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries,
>   res=-113. It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling
>   an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then
>   re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

2. When I click "OK", the following error occurs in the debug tab:

> 05/07 10:56:14: Launching app
>   $ adb install-multiple -r -t
>   C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\GeckoViewTest\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\x86_64\debug\slices\slice_6.apk
>   C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\GeckoViewTest\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\x86_64\debug\slices\slice_0.apk
>   C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\GeckoViewTest\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\x86_64\debug\slices\slice_1.apk
>   C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\GeckoViewTest\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\x86_64\debug\slices\slice_2.apk
>   C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\GeckoViewTest\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\x86_64\debug\slices\slice_7.apk
>   C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\GeckoViewTest\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\x86_64\debug\slices\slice_4.apk
>   C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\GeckoViewTest\app\build\intermediates\resources\instant-run\x86_64\debug\resources-x86_64-debug.apk
>   C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\GeckoViewTest\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\x86_64\debug\slices\slice_5.apk
>   C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\GeckoViewTest\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\x86_64\debug\slices\slice_9.apk
>   C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\GeckoViewTest\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\x86_64\debug\slices\slice_3.apk
>   C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\GeckoViewTest\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\x86_64\debug\slices\slice_8.apk
>   C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\GeckoViewTest\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\x86_64\debug\dep\dependencies.apk
>   C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\GeckoViewTest\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\x86_64\debug\app-x86_64-debug.apk
>   $ adb shell pm uninstall de.example.test.geckoviewtest Unknown
>   failure: Exception occurred while executing:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package:
>   de.example.test.geckoviewtest at
>   com.android.server.pm.Settings.isOrphaned(Settings.java:4289) at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.isOrphaned(PackageManagerService.java:21095)
>   at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.deletePackageVersioned(PackageManagerService.java:17916)
>   at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.uninstall(PackageInstallerService.java:736)
>   at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runUninstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1486)
>   at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:193)
>   at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103) at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21328)
>   at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:634) at
>   android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:532) at
>   android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2821)
>   at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3856)
>   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731) Error while
>   Installing APKs

I added this Code under productFlavors{...} and could install the app:

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

But now my app crashes at:

```
GeckoRuntime runtime = GeckoRuntime.create(this);
```

and I get the following error in the onCreate of my activity:

> 2019-05-07 10:58:31.347 9069-9090/de.example.test.geckoviewtest 
>   E/GeckoLoader: Couldn't load mozglue. Trying native library dir.
>   2019-05-07 10:58:31.368 9069-9090/de.example.test.geckoviewtest
>   E/GeckoLoader: Library doesn't exist when it should. 2019-05-07
>   10:58:31.382 9069-9090/de.example.test.geckoviewtest E/GeckoLoader:
>   Couldn't load
>   /data/user/0/de.example.test.geckoviewtest/lib/libmozglue.so:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/user/0/de.example.test.geckoviewtest/lib/libmozglue.so" not
>   found 2019-05-07 10:58:31.392 9069-9090/de.example.test.geckoviewtest
>   E/GeckoLoader: Couldn't load
>   /data/app-lib/de.example.test.geckoviewtest/libmozglue.so:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app-lib/de.example.test.geckoviewtest/libmozglue.so" not found
>   2019-05-07 10:58:31.409 9069-9090/de.example.test.geckoviewtest
>   E/GeckoLoader: Couldn't load
>   /data/data/de.example.test.geckoviewtest/lib/libmozglue.so:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/data/de.example.test.geckoviewtest/lib/libmozglue.so" not found
>   2019-05-07 10:58:31.420 9069-9090/de.example.test.geckoviewtest
>   W/GeckoLoader: lib/x86/libmozglue.so not found in APK
>   /data/app/de.example.test.geckoviewtest-ED_fDOF4yrCjKrHnYMiPhQ==/base.apk
>   2019-05-07 10:58:31.423 9069-9090/de.example.test.geckoviewtest
>   E/GeckoLoader: Load diagnostics: LOAD mozglue: ABI: x86_64-gcc3, x86:
>   Data: /data/user/0/de.example.test.geckoviewtest, ax=false, ddx=false,
>   -1x=false, -2x=false, nativeLib: /data/app/de.example.test.geckoviewtest-ED_fDOF4yrCjKrHnYMiPhQ==/lib/x86,
>   dirx=false, libx=false
>      --------- beginning of crash
>   2019-05-07 10:58:31.438 9069-9090/de.example.test.geckoviewtest 
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Gecko
>       Process: de.example.test.geckoviewtest, PID: 9069
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: LOAD mozglue: ABI: x86_64-gcc3, x86: Data: /data/user/0/de.example.test.geckoviewtest, ax=false, ddx=false,
>   -1x=false, -2x=false, nativeLib: /data/app/de.example.test.geckoviewtest-ED_fDOF4yrCjKrHnYMiPhQ==/lib/x86,
>   dirx=false, libx=false
>           at org.mozilla.gecko.mozglue.GeckoLoader.doLoadLibrary(GeckoLoader.java:426)
>           at org.mozilla.gecko.mozglue.GeckoLoader.loadMozGlue(GeckoLoader.java:434)
>           at org.mozilla.gecko.GeckoThread.initGeckoEnvironment(GeckoThread.java:287)
>           at org.mozilla.gecko.GeckoThread.run(GeckoThread.java:448)
>        Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/de.example.test.geckoviewtest-ED_fDOF4yrCjKrHnYMiPhQ==/base.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/de.example.test.geckoviewtest-ED_fDOF4yrCjKrHnYMiPhQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/de.example.test.geckoviewtest-ED_fDOF4yrCjKrHnYMiPhQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/de.example.test.geckoviewtest-ED_fDOF4yrCjKrHnYMiPhQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/de.example.test.geckoviewtest-ED_fDOF4yrCjKrHnYMiPhQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/de.example.test.geckoviewtest-ED_fDOF4yrCjKrHnYMiPhQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/de.example.test.geckoviewtest-ED_fDOF4yrCjKrHnYMiPhQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/de.example.test.geckoviewtest-ED_fDOF4yrCjKrHnYMiPhQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/de.example.test.geckoviewtest-ED_fDOF4yrCjKrHnYMiPhQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/de.example.test.geckoviewtest-ED_fDOF4yrCjKrHnYMiPhQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/de.example.test.geckoviewtest-ED_fDOF4yrCjKrHnYMiPhQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/de.example.test.geckoviewtest-ED_fDOF4yrCjKrHnYMiPhQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/de.example.test.geckoviewtest-ED_fDOF4yrCjKrHnYMiPhQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/de.example.test.geckoviewtest-ED_fDOF4yrCjKrHnYMiPhQ==/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libmozglue.so"
>           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1012)
>           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
>           at org.mozilla.gecko.mozglue.GeckoLoader.doLoadLibraryExpected(GeckoLoader.java:347)
>           at org.mozilla.gecko.mozglue.GeckoLoader.doLoadLibrary(GeckoLoader.java:373)
>           at org.mozilla.gecko.mozglue.GeckoLoader.loadMozGlue(GeckoLoader.java:434) 
>           at org.mozilla.gecko.GeckoThread.initGeckoEnvironment(GeckoThread.java:287) 
>           at org.mozilla.gecko.GeckoThread.run(GeckoThread.java:448)

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the gecko build doesn't contains the proper library `mozglue` for the architecture you are targeting (i.e. your devices needs x86 and u're building arm64).
You need to be sure to import the right one for your architecture

```
implementation "org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview-arm64-v8a:69.0.20190903125908" //for arm 64
implementation "org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview-armeabi-v7a:69.0.20190903125908" //for arm v7
implementation "org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview-x86:69.0.20190903125908" //for x86 32 bit
implementation "org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview-x86_64:69.0.20190903125908" //for x86 64 bit
```